# What is the most unobtrusive way to add a layer of security for a private beta of website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, beta-testing

Let's say I have an ASP.NET site (MVC in this case) that uses Forms authentication and a typical membership system. The site allows both authenticated and anonymous users.

When I release the site as a private beta I want to add another layer of security on top of the application, like [superuser's](https://superuser.com/beta-access) simple password system, for example. Once a user has passed this layer of security, I still want my forms authentication/membership system in place so beta testers can view the site as authenticated or anonymous users.

What's the most unobtrusive way to achieve this? I'm looking for the easiest solution that will require the least amount of new or modified code. E.g. I don't want to modify every controller to check for a special cookie. There must be a better way...

There's a [very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894931/setting-up-a-private-beta-for-a-website) question here, but it seems the site in question (once public) will only serve anonymous requests, so it doesn't necessarily compare to my situation. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894931/setting-up-a-private-beta-for-a-website/894945#894945) suggests ServerFault used some cookie system, but there are no further details about how it might have been implemented.

Answer (score 5):

Implement security at server level, in IIS and add the accounts/passwords in Active Directory of Windows running the IIS server.

You won't need to change any of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I know you don't want to modify your current controllers but here's what I did for a similar behaviour.
I've created a custom ActionFilterAttribute that I've given to every controller that requires to have that specific access check. You can have something like this :

```
public class CheckBetaAccess : ActionFilterAttribute {
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        if (!canAccess) {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData["someViewData"] = "some text";
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult {
                ViewName = "the-view-anonymous-users-should-see",
                ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData
            };
            filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I decorated my controllers :

```
[CheckBetaAccess]
public class SomeController : Controller {
    //....
}
```