# Securing an ASP.NET MVC application for beta testing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hey all. I have an ASP.NET MVC application that I am going to be deploying to a live server soon. Theoretically, I would like to password protect the application while I'm beta testing without modifying the underlying code base or membership within the application. I will have several people beta testing, so it is compulsory that it is available on the web. A simple scenario:

1. User navigates to the application under beta
2. Perhaps an HttpHandler will process the request and redirect them to an interstitial, temporary login page where they have to enter a beta password to access the application

Stackoverflow used a similar technique when they were under beta test. Any ideas?

An edit for clarification. I don't have access to IIS for this particular application because I'm using a managed host.

Comment: Can you provide an interface for the membership provider, and change out the implementation of that interface when you go live?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. I'm using OpenID as my membership provider.

Comment: I asked a similar question before but it didn't get much activity, so I'm glad to see this asked again. More input here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171897/what-is-the-most-unobtrusive-way-to-add-a-layer-of-security-for-a-private-beta-of

Answer (score 1):

A couple ideas:

1. Use windows authentication for the whole application/site in IIS
2. The idea you mentioned is also a good approach IMO, implementation would probably be flexible in that case.

Comment: I agree on just letting IIS handle it. Just a couple of clicks and then you don't spend any time building something you'll have to undo later.

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to mention that I can't access IIS because I'm using a managed solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could wire up a quick custom AuthorizeAttribute that checks for a custom Auth cookie. Just decorate your controllers with it under beta and delete them when you're ready to go.

Something like this (PS - Did this on the fly without testing):

```
    public class BetaTestAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            //if(cookie checks out ok)
                //return true;
            //else
                //httpContext.Response.Redirect("BetaLoginPage");

            return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

Have an action method like so:

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult BetaLogin(string username, string password)
        {
            if(username == "whatever" && password == "whatever")
            {
                 //create custom cookie
                 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
                return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you crate a new ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio, you automatically get an AccountController that uses ASP.NET's underlying MembershipProvider to provide a login mechanism.

Even if you don't have it in your final application, you can use it as a temporary solution until you get your real security mechanism up and running.

It requires you to set up a SQL Server database for those ASP.NET services, but depending on how familiar you are with that, you can do it within ten minutes to a couple of hours.

When the public beta is over, you can just discard the AccountController and the database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with dhulk -- use Windows Authentication on IIS.  That route will allow you to avoid putting *any* authentication code in your application.  Simpler is better, and I'd want to avoid doing the work to implement a membership system then to *un*-implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a simple login View which sets a Session that gets checked on `Session_Start()` in your *Global.asax* file... Like so:

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
    if (!Convert.ToBoolean(Session["authenticated"]))
    {
        // Redirect to the login View
    }
}
```

When you are ready to open up your application for everyone, just remove the View and the three lines of code in your *Global.asax* file.

Comment: Well, I thought about that, but unfortunately, Session State is not available in the Application_Start event.

Comment: How about using `Session_Start()` then?

Comment: Just checked. You are able to access the Session object on `Session_Start()`. There ya go :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the good old RoleProvider and create a Beta role and check it via Authorize
2. Create your own AuthorizeAttribute and check for the IP address or a cookie
   .